# Active consumer not discovered from zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am new to apache kafka and I have set up a kafka-broker with zookeeper on top of my self-deployed kubernetes cluster. (2 seperate pods)

There is no noticeable error logs and everything works fine including:

- creating topics
- producing messages through bin/kafka-console-producer.sh
- subscribing(consuming) messages through bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh
- Listing topics in zookeeper CLI ( ls /brokers/ids )

Except:

- listing active consumers in the [kafka offset monitoring tool](http://quantifind.github.io/KafkaOffsetMonitor/)

when I try listing active consumers in zookeeper CLI or view active consumers in the monitoring tool, I get empty results as well.(while I have a consumer session running describe above)

Integration between zookeeper and kafka broker seems to work find since when I try:

```sh
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1] ls /brokers/topics
[topic1, topic2] 
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 2] ls /consumers
[]
```

Am I missing something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consumer data are not stored in Zookeeper anymore (since 0.9). Consumer group data are now stored directly in Kafka.

To check the state of Consumer Groups, you should use the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` tool. For example:

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server [HOST:PORT] --group [GROUP]
```

Note that only Consumers that are part of a group that commit offsets are visible. By default the `kafka-console-consumer.sh` does not. You need to specify `--group [GROUP]` to enable it.